# SQL - Select instance type

Tags: sql, oracle, inheritance, user-defined-types

I am using Oracle DB and I have this type:

```
CREATE TYPE t_foo AS OBJECT
(a VARCHAR2(20))
NOT FINAL;
```

And also these subtypes

```
CREATE TYPE t_foo1 UNDER t_foo() NOT FINAL;
CREATE TYPE t_foo2 UNDER t_foo() NOT FINAL;
```

I have a table of type t_foo where I can also store subtypes of t_foo

```
CREATE TABLE foo OF t_foo;
```

Now my question is how can I do a query like this

```
SELECT a, type FROM foo;
```

and get the instance type of each row like ths:

```
__________________
| a   | type     |
__________________
| bla | t_foo1   |
| ble | t_foo2   |
| bli | t_foo1   |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SQL> insert into foo values(t_foo1('alpha'));
1 row inserted.

SQL> insert into foo values(t_foo2('bravo'));
1 row inserted.

SQL> insert into foo values(t_foo('charlie'));
1 row inserted.

SQL> commit;
Commit complete.

SQL> select
  f.a,
  ut.type_name as type_name
from foo f
  join user_types ut
    on ut.typeid = sys_typeid(value(f));

A                    TYPE_NAME
-------------------- ----------
alpha                T_FOO1    
bravo                T_FOO2    
charlie              T_FOO
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I found.

It is not general, but if you have a limited number of known types, it is a quite simple query.

```
SELECT f.a,
    CASE WHEN f IS OF (t_foo1) THEN 't_foo1'
         WHEN f IS OF (t_foo2) THEN 't_foo2'
         ELSE 'other' END as type
FROM foo f
```